# Convert string with bytes to byte string

Tags: string, python-3.x, byte

I need to convert a string with bytes (string view) to byte object in Python.

```
string = input() # string = '\xff\x00B'
bs = samefunc(string) # typeof(bs) == bytes, len(bs) == 3
print(bs[0]) # b'\xff'
print(bs[1]) # b'\x00'
print(bs[2]) # b'B'
```

In my app the string input is so large the self parser will be very slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "the self parser"? Also, if `bs` is a bytes object, `bs[0]` will be 255, not `b'\xff'`, if that matters.

Comment: You're right! `bs` is bytestring, and `bs[0] == 255`.
Self parser is a selfwrite function, which parse string to normal symblos and `\xXX` constructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval`, which is more secure if the input is not 100% in your hands):

```
s = input() # s = '\\xff\\x00B'
bs = eval("b'%s'" % s) # typeof(bs) == bytes, len(bs) == 3
print(bs[0]) # 255
print(bs[1]) # 0
print(bs[2]) # 66
```

Comment: It's dont't working. Because `s` get from user `input`. And '\' is escaping. In program `s == `\\xff\\x00B`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to work if the input is escaped.